# Tkinter OOP More than one Entry

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, tkinter, tkinter-entry

So, I decided to revamp my coursework app to use OOP for Tkinter and a problem arose.

I use 4 entries for the login screen, 2 for login and 2 for register - each being username and password per side.

Problem I have arose here:

This is my OOP class:

```
class windowGen:
    def __init__(self, master, title, geometry, background):
        self.master = master
        self.title = title
        self.geometry = geometry
        self.background = background
        master.title(title)
        master.geometry(geometry)
        master.configure(bg=background)
    def createLabel(self, master, contents, fgcolor, bgcolor, horizontal, vertical):
        self.label = Label(master, text=contents, justify=LEFT, fg=fgcolor, bg=bgcolor, font="TkFixedFont")
        self.label.place(x=horizontal, y=vertical)
    def getEntry(self):
        return self.entry.get()
    def exitWindow(self):
        self.master.destroy()
    def createEntry(self, master, horizontal, vertical):
        self.entry = Entry(master)
        self.entry.place(x=horizontal,y=vertical)
```

Now, the problems are createEntry and getEntry. These work perfect when there is only 1 entry per window, but now I have 4. How do I manage 4 entries when I only use self.entry?

TL;DR: How does one manage entries using OOP Tkinter when you have more than 1 entry box on a window?

Written in Python 3.9.0, latest version of TK and Tcl.

Comment: Use a list object maybe? with the indexes being each entry

Comment: @Evorage How would I do that exactly..? I am new to OOP for Python so I am not really sure.

Comment: I think you can just pass in a list when create a class variable such as `thing = classthing([0,1,2,3,4])` so that list is whatever you decide in __init__

Comment: @Evorage Okay i sort of understand that? Not sure how I could make it work, especially with the createEntry needing the x and y coordinates to place them all...

Comment: I have a temporary fix in that I can create the nooby way of just having ```variable = Entry(window)``` and placing it, then using tkinter's .get() function but it's just clunky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a dictionary to store the created entries using an unique name as the key:

```py
class windowGen:
    def __init__(self, master, title, geometry, background):
        self.master = master
        self.title = title
        self.geometry = geometry
        self.background = background
        master.title(title)
        master.geometry(geometry)
        master.configure(bg=background)
        self.entries = {}  # dictionary to store the entries
    def createLabel(self, master, contents, fgcolor, bgcolor, horizontal, vertical):
        self.label = Label(master, text=contents, justify=LEFT, fg=fgcolor, bg=bgcolor, font="TkFixedFont")
        self.label.place(x=horizontal, y=vertical)
    def getEntry(self, name): # get value of entry specified by name
        return self.entries[name].get()
    def exitWindow(self):
        self.master.destroy()
    def createEntry(self, master, horizontal, vertical, name=None):
        entry = Entry(master)
        entry.place(x=horizontal,y=vertical)
        name = name or str(entry)  # use passed name or tkinter internal name
        self.entries[name] = entry
        return name  # return the name as the entry ID
```

Then you can use the name to access the entry like below:

```
root = Tk()
gen = windowGen(root, "title", "400x200", "gold")
e1 = gen.createEntry(root, 10, 10)
...
gen.getEntry(e1)
```

Comment: You. Are. Amazing.